# Revmob adds not recieving in iphone os 6.0

Tags: ios, revmob

When I am integrating `RevMob` In my App With `RevMob_ios-sdk-4`. i am getting a console message `"No Ads available for this device/country at this moment, or your App ID is paused. (204)"`.
But the `RevMob` is doing fine in testing mode. Previously it was working fine. The adds were showing  but from couple of days there is a problem in my App and console message is being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of RevMob that is `RevMob 5.2.7` has been released recently. Upgrading to this version might solve your problem.

***EDIT:-***
RevMob is working absolutely fine in Testing mode but giving the same error as you mentioned above in production mode. I have tested it on device as well as on simulator.

**EDIT2: I contacted to RevMob team regarding the issues and got the below reply:**

This message is normal. Don't worry.

It either means that currently there are no apps to be promoted in your device or you have already downloaded all the available apps at the moment.

If you want to make sure integration was done properly, you can use our Testing Mode (http://sdk.revmob.com/). But make sure to turn it off before submitting the app ;)

Comment: Currently use other SDKs like ChartBoost as there is no solution to this problem right now.

Comment: also having this issue with revmob att he moment.  Switched away from their sdk until there is a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of testing mode is testing, so when start testing mode with ads it'll display ads no matter what.

This message usually reflect what it says, or your app is paused on [RevMob Console](http://console.revmob.com), or there is no ads available for your device at the moment.

If you app is not paused, you can try in another device. It's also possible that they don't have ads for your device at your country.

**EDIT**: This usually is a temporary issue and there is nothing that you can do if this case, this also don't mean that your app won't show ads on premium markets like US.